# ConvertExcelToCSVProcessor of Apache nifi automatically convert year format from 'yyyy' to 'yy'

Tags: apache-poi, apache-nifi

I am designing flow using apache NIFI where I need to convert excel to CSV and then pass it to downstream system. For excel to CSV conversion I am using ConvertExcelToCSVProcessor and facing issue in date conversion where year is getting converted into short format from long i.e. from 'yyyy' to 'yy'.

I have d/m/yyyy format data available in excel

How to avoid such format changing while converting excel to CSV using apache nifi

Comment: I don't know much about nifi but they might be able to uptake this change in POI - https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=65703 - it's not yet released - in short term you might be able to subclass ConvertExcelToCSVProcessor and to have the subclass modify dates that have 2 digit years.

Comment: In your excel file, you might be better to use a custom date format that has 4 digit year instead of relying on the built-in excel ones which can be a bit weird

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am working on a similar project, NiFi Excel to CSV, and the solution found is:

- set the property `Format Cell Values` to **true**
- force the format of cells to excel with the Format Cells function

[image]

Comment: I have configured "Format Cell Values" to true only but excel formatting is not in my hand. I am getting this excel as Input from some other system

Comment: from the tests I performed, the date comes in MM/dd/yy format without forcing, after you can use RecordPath processor for modify date.
 
https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/record-path-guide.html

Comment: After excel to csv conversion, I am changing format using RecordPath and it was worked for me